# Most efficient way to use hover over image effects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to answer my question, I'm just posting to see if there's **a better way to do what I'm already doing.**

Let's say I'm making a website that sells 4 different types of posters. I want the user to see each of the posters in a row. and when they hover over each picture the image will change to show the price, and measurements of the poster.

How I achieved this:

```
<ul>
<li> image link here using onmouseover and onmouseout for hover over effects </li>
<li> same as above </li>
<li> same as above </li>
<li> same as above </li>
</ul
```

Then I just styled the list to remove bullets and aligned it horizontally. Now here's my question... I am currently using onmouseover and onmouseout for hover over effects Because you need 2 images in order to achieve this you need a lot of data, especially if you're going to do this for, say, a grid of 25 images for an art portfolio.

Is this a bad way to get a hover over effect? I'm assuming because I'm new at web-development anything I can throw onto a webpage is going to be somewhat crude and not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have another div within the `<li>` containing the info you wanted. Have this absolutely positioned over the image and then show it on hover using `opacity`.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/Ifwrd)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /><div class="info">Info here</div></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /><div class="info">Info here</div></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /><div class="info">Info here</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul,li {
   list-style: none; 
}

li {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
img {
   display: block;
}

.info {
   opacity: 0;
   color: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
   background: red;
   .transition(opacity 0.5s ease);
}

li:hover .info {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Have updated the demo. It's using less but the CSS should also be visible. This allows a lot of flexibility and I always feel that its better not to rely on JS for these kind of things.

Comment: Oh this is cool, I like how it has a fade-in effect and it's not as abrupt as onmouseover. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @user3473001 if either this or the other answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you :)

You can line `.image` next to each other with `display: inline-block;`

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/bm54L/)

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X200" />
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.text {
    display: none;
}

img { 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
img:hover + .text, .text:hover {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really cool. Would this happen to have a lower load time than the onmouseover and onmouseout functions I'm using?

Comment: This would be faster than loading javascript :)